# Excel ActiveX checkbox linked to cell on separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, linker

I have a very large matrix with employees in rows and training objectives in columns. I have managed to pull each objective and employees name in rows and columns.  I am trying to create a form where checkboxes will populate the matrix.  I cannot seem to link the checkbox with the matrix cells.

My variables give the correct information when sent to a MsgBox, I just can't figure out the checkboxes.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim r As String
    Dim c As String
        r = Range("MatrixUpdate!H2").Value
        c = Range("MatrixUpdate!Q7").Value
    
    Worksheets("Matrix").Cells(r, c).Value = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXYn2.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax1r6.png]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, I needed to set them as "Integer" not Strings. Did that any it works. I also put it in an IF.

```
Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
        r = Range("MatrixUpdate!H2").Value
        c = Range("MatrixUpdate!Q7").Value
      
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Worksheets("Matrix").Cells(r, c).Value = 1
    Else
        Worksheets("Matrix").Cells(r, c).Value = 0
    End If
   
End Sub
```